# Convert from JavaScript v.splice(vi, 1) to Go

Tags: javascript, go

I know nothing about JavaScript.

Assume that v contains a list of positive integers, vi is an index value, say current vi = 0.

I would like to know how to convert v.splice(vi, 1) to Golang

Is .splice() is equivalent to slices?

Comment: "Is .splice() is equivalent to slices?" --- no.

Comment: then how to convert it? i have no idea

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to understand it enough to be able to convert it. Or simply hire somebody. There is no 3rd way.

Comment: Provide at least a code example to clarify the problem you are facing...

Comment: @zerkms I DID NOT HOW IT WORKS. i just wanted to know how it is done.

Comment: How _what_ is done? You provided nothing in your question.

Comment: @Johnny some go users are not forgiving. my quetion has always been downvoted. SO i just ask some basic question. you can refer to bserdar's answer. it is what i am looking for.

Comment: @zerkms just look at bserdar's answer. seriously.

Comment: @newguyinstuckoverflow Then you should be more clear with the question... How to remove an item from a slice...otherwise people could only guess. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v.splice(vi, 1)` removes 1 element from `vi`. To do the same in go, you can do:

```
append(v[:vi],v[vi+1:]...)
```

That is, first get the slice up to `vi`, then add all the elements after `vi`.

Answer (score 0):

From : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

**Syntax**
array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)

Parameter: index
Description. An integer that specifies at what position to add/remove items, Use negative values to specify the position from the end of the array.

Parameter :howmany(Optional)
Description: The number of items to be removed. If set to 0, no items will be removed

Parameter:item1, ..., itemX (Optional)
Description: The new item(s) to be added to the array

You may visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_splice for trying it yourself